# Cannot set property '$scope variable' of undefined in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Facing error while trying to copy one variable to another

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myWelcome = "Welcome"
    var vm = this,
        parent = $scope.summary,
        results = $scope.results,
        matches = {
            "value":"John"
        };
    parent.def = angular.copy(matches);
    $scope.myWelcome =  parent.def;
});
```

//Facing this error, someone please guide:

```
   TypeError: Cannot set property 'def' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:11:14)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106)
    at O.instance (angular.js:11076)
    at p (angular.js:9939)
    at f (angular.js:9248)
    at angular.js:9113
    at angular.js:1960
    at m.$eval (angular.js:18542)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line: `parent.def = angular.copy(matches);`, `parent` is equal to `$scope.summary`.

So you are trying to do the equivalent of `$scope.summary.def = angular.copy(matches)`. Since `$scope.summary` is undefined, an error is thrown.

You can fix it by defining `$scope.summary` first as an empty object: `$scope.summary = {}`.